# Вызвать клавиатуру вручную Android

Tags: android, opengl

Добрый день! Собственно, у меня есть работающее приложение. При запуске Активити на экране отображается не layout, а отрисовка с помощью OpenGL. В определенный момент мне необходимо получить от пользователя текст. Подскажите, как вызвать клавиатуру и получить текст?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызвать

```
InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager)  YourActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if(m != null){
                    m.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(
                        yourView.getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY,
                        InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }
```

в этом методе YourActivity - активити, которая нуждается в клавиатуре, yourView - view, которому нужна клавиатура - она не может быть так сама по себе.

прятать этим же методом. (он вообще то переключает. Но есть ещё методы showSoftInput, hideSoftInputFromWindow и подобные).

Теперь дело осталось за малым нужно view должно уметь обрабатывать нажатия кнопок.

```
yourView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
//
}
};
```

Comment: Спасибо! А вот маленькое дополнение. Можно ли получать текст с клавиатуры БЕЗ полей ввода. Я так понимаю, что в Вашем примере выше View - это, например, EditText. На iOs можно вызвать клавиатуру и получать с неё текст без других виджетов. Хотелось бы и здесь такое реализовать. В любом случае, большео спасибо за ответ!

Comment: InputMethodManager.showSoftInput()

Comment: В моем примере View может быть любым классом. Вы получаете  нажатия кнопок. А дальше делайте с ними все что угодно - например, складывайте в строку. Правда нужно будет обработать кнопку backspace, стрелочки, но это уже от задачи зависит. Может Вам нужно ввести два символа для морского боя.